Update on MySQL
I'm having an issue with a very simple update on MySQL. I'm sure the problem is my total ignorance of this kind of database. I usually work on SQL Server and have seen that update statements have different syntax on MySQL, but I don't understand the cause of the problem.
Premises: I had to reproduce a db on my laptop from a dump file. I have now to update two columns of a table to replace all the values with the values contained in another table. Both tables have 9734 rows.
Code: This is what I wrote:
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
SET table1.nome = table2.nome;

Issue: I ran this code, but it's still running after 20 minutes. I don't understand why.

Speed of a query largely depends on 4 things: 1) amount of data to retrieve and / or modify 2) availability of useful indexes 3) mysql configuration 4) what other things the computer running the database is doing.  You need to review all 4 of these categories to find out the why. Even the data is a question mark for us. If the id column in both tables contain the same value in all rows, then 9732*9732 number of rows will be used in the operation. The answer to the duplicate question will help you with this.
